# How to create a graph with vertices weight in python with igraph?

Tags: python, graph, igraph, weighted

I searched but found there are many examples about how to create a graph with edges weight, but none of them shows how to create a graph with vertices weight. I start to wonder if it is possible.

If a vertices-weighted graph can be created with igraph, then is it possible to calculate the weighted independence or other weighted numbers with igraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no functions in igraph that accept arguments for weighted vertices. However, the SANTA package that is a part of the Bioconductor suite for R does have routines for weighted vertices, if you are willing to move to R for this. (Seems like *maybe* you can run [bioconductor in python](https://pythonhosted.org/rpy2-bioconductor-extensions/).)

Another hacky option is the use (when possible) unweighted routines from igraph and then back in the weights. E.g. something like this for weighted maximal independent sets:

```
def maxset(graph,weight):
    ms = g.maximal_independent_vertex_sets()
    w = []
    t = []
    for i in range(0, 150):
        m = weights.loc[weights['ids'].isin(ms[i]),"weights"]
        w.append(m)
        s = sum(w[i])
        t.append(s) 
    return(ms[t.index(max(t))])
maxset(g,weights)
```

(Where weights is a two column data frame with column 1 = vertex ids and column 2 = weights). This gets the maximal independent set taking vertex weights into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Which package can cover more functions no matter in python or R or other softwares? Do you have some recommendation?

Comment: @EdenHarder There really isn't one package that covers everything. I mostly use the statnet/sna/network/ergm suite of packages in R, since I mainly do social network analysis. igraph in R, C, and python is a bit more graph-theory oriented to me. Networkx in python is geared toward complex network analysis. Really, it depends on what you want to achieve. I find some combo of igraph and statnet work for me.

Comment: There are a lot of smaller packages in R that cover more specific networks, like asnipe and enaR, which focus on network analysis for ecologists and biologists.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for graph-theory oriented ones, it seems that Sagemath is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `vs` class to define vertices and their attributes in `igraph`.

As example for setting weight on vertices, taken from documentation:

http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.VertexSeq-class.html

```
g=Graph.Full(3) # generate a full graph as example

for idx, v in enumerate(g.vs):
    v["weight"] = idx*(idx+1) # set the 'weight' of vertex to integer, in function of a progressive index

>>> g.vs["weight"]
[0, 2, 6]
```

Note that a sequence of vertices are called through g.vs, here g the instance of your Graph object.

I suggested you this page, I found it practical to look for iGraph methods here:
http://igraph.org/python/doc/identifier-index.html